# Simple modification of Newton's method problem

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, newton-raphson

Since you can transform Newton's recurrence relation to the original equation $f(x)=0$ by considering the limiting case as $n$ tends to infinity, it's not surprising you can also do it the other way around (if you know what you are doing). Starting with $f(x)=0$, you can transform it to an equation with an $x$ on the LHS that will play the role of $x_{n+1}$ and some $g(x)$ on the RHS where you can replace the $x$ with $x_{n}$. If you do it just right, you get the same recurrence relation just as if you applied the Newton's method directly. For example, take $f(x)=x^2-x-1$:

Newton's recurrence relation would be:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}^2+1}{2x_{n}-1}$$

And by starting with $f(x)=0$ we can get the same:

$$x^2-x-1=0$$
$$x^2-x=1$$
$$x^2-x+x^2=1+x^2$$
$$2x^2-x=x^2+1$$
$$x=\frac{x^2+1}{2x-1}$$
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+1}{2x_n-1}$$

Now, suppose you don't know what you are doing. Suppose that, in the third step you "parametrize" the recurrence as such (you pick some $a\neq1$):

$$x^2-x+a x^2=1+a x^2$$
$$(a+1)x^2-x=ax^2+1$$
$$x=\frac{ax^2+1}{(a+1)x-1}$$
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{ax_{n}^2+1}{(a+1)x_{n}-1}$$

Does this converge to the same values as Newton's recurrence relation? If not, how can you test for which values of $a$ it does and for which ones it doesn't? And since it converging for a single $a\neq1$ would imply these non-Newton recurrence relations can sometimes work, how far can you push them? For example, $x_{n+1}=x_n^2-1$ most definitely doesn't work. But how can you check to be sure?

Comment: Are you asking for this equation specific or in general ?

Comment: Notice there is also a thing like " convergeance speed "

Comment: I would like to know in general, but felt like I need a concrete example to explain what I was on about.

Comment: if you use calculus you can compute what works and how. For instance you can compute the derivative at the fixpoint to see if your iteration goes towards it or if it goes away from it.